# How do I work with the 1st and least element in Observable?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

Let's say I've got an `Observable<Player>` and I'd like to map this to another `Observable<Integer>`, where `Integer` equals to `player.height`, but there's a condition: I'd like to map all players but the very first and last one (we should check one more thing for them). So in iterative programming it'll sth like this:

```
heights = []
num_of_players = len(players)
for idx in len(num_of_players):
if (idx == 0 or idx == num_of_players - 1):
   if (isGoodEnough(players[idx]):
      heights.append(player.height)
else:
   heights.append(player.height)
return height
```

How do I rewrite this in Rx way (you should assume I'm given Observable instead of List)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```java
Observable<Player> players;

Single<Integer> playerHeight(int playerId);
```

You have to split the sequence into first, middle and last with `publish(Function)`s and then combine them back together:

```java
players
.publish(sharedPlayers -> {
    return Observable.merge(
       // work only on the very first player
       sharedPlayers.take(1)
           .filter(firstPlayer -> isGoodEnough(firstPlayer))
           .flatMapSingle(firstPlayer -> playerHeight(firstPlayer.playerId)),
       // work with not the first and not the last
       sharedPlayers.skip(1).skipLast(1)
           .flatMapSingle(midPlayers -> playerHeight(midPlayers .playerId)),
       // work with the last which shouldn't be the first again
       sharedPlayers.skip(1).takeLast(1)
           .filter(lastPlayer -> isGoodEnough(lastPlayer))
           .flatMapSingle(lastPlayer-> playerHeight(lastPlayer.playerId))
    );
})
.subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Please adapt this solution as necessary.